# How to create dynamic references in VueFire?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I'm trying to create refs dynamically:

My first ref works because it's hardcoded but the second doesn't, apparently because it's dynamic:

```
 firebase: function(){
    return {
        categories: db.ref('categories'),
        subcategories: db.ref('categories').child(this.addItem.category)
    }   
 }
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a dynamic db ref by using `vm.$bindAsObject` found in the [vue-fire docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire). I used it in the created hook with a project id, like so:

```
created () {
  this.$bindAsObject('project', db.ref('projects/' + this.$route.params.id))
}
```

If you've already got a db.ref binding you might have to `vm.$unbind` but I haven't had to do that yet.