# Firebase Reference from Route ID

Tags: vuejs2, vuefire

I'm trying to dynamically set the firebase reference based on the id of the URL. I'm using Vue and VueFire. Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <h4>name: {{anObject.name}}</h4>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import db from '@/js/firebase.js'

  export default {
    props: ['id'],
    firebase: {
      anObject: {
        source: db.ref(this.getPath),
        //source: db.ref('path/id'),
        asObject: true,
        cancelCallback: function () {console.log("Cancel")},
        readyCallback: function () {console.log("Ready")}
     },
   computed: {
     getPath () {
       return 'path/' + this.id
     }
   }
 </script>
```

At the moment the 'anObject' object doesn't produce any data (no errors are raised). When I hard code the path (currently shown commented out) everything works as expected. I guess the problem is related to the id property not having a value at the time the 'anObject' is created? If so can I update the reference in a lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157125/how-to-create-dynamic-references-in-vuefire). Basically I needed to wait for the created hook and then define the reference (noting not to define it anywhere else!).

```
  created () {
    this.$bindAsObject('anObject', db.ref('path/' + this.$route.params.id))
  },
```